# Equivalent of the Matlab function `eps` in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In Matlab `eps` has the following feature:

> d = eps(x), where x has data type single or double, returns the positive distance from abs(x) to the next larger floating-point number of the same precision as x.

What is the equivalent way of computing this in Python or Numpy?

When searching for the answer, I found references to `np.finfo(np.float64).eps`, which is only the equivalent of `eps('double')` in Matlab.

Comment: Wouldn't np.finfo(np.float32).eps work for single precision?

Comment: The finfo command only gives information about the datatype itself. `eps(x)` is dependent on the current value of `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be searching for [numpy spacing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.spacing.html). Here an example:

```
import numpy as np

for i in [1e-2, 1, 1e5, 1e10]:
    print(f'Spacing for {i:.4e} :\t {np.spacing(i):.4e}')
```

And here the output:

```
Spacing for 1.0000e-02 :         1.7347e-18
Spacing for 1.0000e+00 :         2.2204e-16
Spacing for 1.0000e+05 :         1.4552e-11
Spacing for 1.0000e+10 :         1.9073e-06
```